# Simple telegram text-quest bot, wont go too deep into function

Tags: python, telebot

I'm learning Python and I wanted to make a simple telegram bot out of terminal text game I made before.

I don't know what is the issue, but my guess is that the function is too big.

When it reaches the bear room buttons simply wont work, they are sending same value - doesn't matter which one i press. The script isnt crashing but wont jump into next state.

I tested the script till the 6th room (bear room)

I tried switching the room, it seems that no matter what room will be there - it wont identify difference between callback data, like as if I were pressing 1 button, even if there could be 4 of them.

How to fix this?

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types
from random import randint
import random

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])

def start_game(message):
    user = message.chat.id

    states[user] = 0
    inventories[user] = []

    bot.send_message(user, "Добро пожаловать в игру!")

    process_state(user, states[user], inventories[user])
    
  

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def user_answer(call):
    user = call.message.chat.id
    process_answer(user, call.data)

def process_state(user, state, inventory):
    kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    bot.send_photo(user, pictures[state])
    #  dead state
    if state == -1:
        bot.send_message(user, "Вы проиграли. Начать заново: /start")
        return
    #  starting state with 4 doors
    elif state == 0:
        kb.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="пойти направо", callback_data="1"))
        kb.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="пойти налево", callback_data="2"))
        kb.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="пойти назад", callback_data="3"))
        kb.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="пойти прямо", callback_data="4"))
        
        bot.send_message(user, "Вы в оказались в темном подземелье, перед вами 4 прохода.", reply_markup=kb)
(and here is 11 more states)
def process_answer(user, answer):
    #  game start
    if states[user] == 0:
        # 1st button: пойти направо
        if answer == "1":
            #  переводит в комнату с подземным озером
            states[user] = 1
            # 3rd button: пойти назад
        elif answer == "3":
            # Player loses, set state to -1
            states[user] = -1
            # 4th button: пойти прямо
        elif answer == "4":
            states[user] = 2
        else:
            #  2nd button: пойти налево(при условии, что state = 0)
            if "key" in inventories[user]:
                bot.send_message(user,
                                 "Перед вами закрытая дверь. Вы пробуете открыть ее ключем, и дверь поддается. За ней блестит артефакт, вы не знаете зачем он вам, но берете с собой на всякий случай.")
                states[user] = 0
                inventories[user].append("artifact")
            else: 
                bot.send_message(user, "Перед вами закрытая дверь, и, кажется, без ключа ее не открыть. Придется вернуться обратно.")
                states[user] = 0  #  возвращает в старт

    (and here is 11 more answers)

    process_state(user, states[user], inventories[user])

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```